# What is the use of base.xml file of sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What is the purpose of BASE.xml file located at 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\BASE.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is used for defining Sharepoint base list types (Document library etc).

**Edit**

Found the [current MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479188.aspx)

Here is the snippet regarding Base.xml:

> BASE.XML: Provides the schemas used in creating the
>   Lists, Documents, and UserInfo tables in the database when a new site
>   is provisioned.

The link also provides documentation for all of the other Major CAML files.

Good to know:

> With the exception of DocIcon.xml, Microsoft does not support
>   modifying any of the built-in files that are installed with SharePoint
>   Foundation. In most cases, you can supplement or override the effects
>   of these files with files of your own.